# Spacy taking too long to run as compared to before

Tags: nlp, spacy

The spacy module is taking too long to vectorize a sentence.

```
for question in Question_Set:
   sentence = nlp(question)
```

The dataset contains nearly 300k questions. Initially, this code was taking 15 minutes to run. However, now when I am running the same code, it is showing near about 4 hours. The spacy module is taking too long to vectorize a sentence.

Comment: A hint, most people outside India will have no idea what are "lakh questions", so please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: What changed between when processing was fast and processing was slow? Did you change your data or upgrade spaCy or what? What model / pipeline are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nlp.pipe`.

```py
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, n_process=2, batch_size=2000):
    # do something here
```

`nlp.pipe` allows for both multiprocessing and batching. You can specify the number of cores your machine has and a batch size that is reasonable.

An additional speed improvement could be achieved by disabling components of the `nlp()` pipeline that you do not need. For example,

```py
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, n_process=2, batch_size=2000, disable=['ner', 'lemmatizer']):
    # do something here
```

Find more on how to speed up the processing pipeline here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines.